# Installing collections in Ansible Tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I've been following https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html#installing-a-collection-from-a-git-repository to try and install my collection using a `collections/requirements.yml` file but I'm getting some errors.

Tower version: v3.8.6

Galaxy Version: v2.13.2

My galaxy file looks like:

```
---
namespace: my_ansible_collections
name: ansible_cert_renew_collection
version: 1.0.0
description: Collection of role to renew certs on servers
readme: readme.md
authors:
  - Myself
tags:
  - collection
  - certificate
repository: https://github.com/philthynz/ansible-collections.git
```

And my `collections/requirements.yml` looks like:

```
---
collections:
  - name: my_ansible_collections.ansible_cert_renew_collection
    source: https://github.com/philthynz/ansible-collections.git
    type: git
    version: main
```

When trying to sync the Tower project, the job has an error:

```
TASK [fetch galaxy collections from collections/requirements.yml] **************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["ansible-galaxy", "collection", "install", "-r", "collections/requirements.yml", "--collections-path", "/var/lib/awx/projects/.__awx_cache/_1449__tsp_certificate_renewals_phil/stage/requirements_collections"], "delta": "0:00:01.868622", "end": "2022-11-16 06:42:46.339223", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-11-16 06:42:44.470601", "stderr": "ERROR! Failed to parse Galaxy response from 'https://github.com/philthynz/ansible-collections' as JSON:\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\" data-color-mode=\"auto\" data-light-theme=\"light\" data-dark-theme=\"dark\" data-a11y-animated-images=\"system\">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n  <link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"https://github.githubassets.com\">\n  <link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com\">\n  <link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com\">\n  <link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"https://user-images.…
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what's the full error? i'm not sure, but try `yamllint ./` in your folder, and fix those issues.

Comment: That is the full error from Tower. Ansible Lint didn't find any issues. It works locally so I doubt it would.

Comment: A 'roles/requirements.yml' file works in Tower. So I'll just use that.